# Have an image fill all the remaining whitespace with css

Tags: css

So I have a fixed width header taking up 200px with a float left. I need an image to fill the rest of the window on the right hand side. If I use width 100%, the image fills the entirety of the window and drops below the header.

Here's what I have:

```
header {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}


#banner-image {
  width: 100%;;
}
```

Comment: I think we need more code.  HTML would be good.  plunkr would be even better.

Comment: @DaveBush dear lord NEVER use that rubbish called plunkr...Use jsfiddle or codepen instead. Plunkr doesn't work at all on devices with a small screen...

Comment: atleast show us an image of your need provice html code

Comment: Post more code, but if I understand well, `float:right` on image, with `width:calc (100% - 200px);` will get the job done

Comment: @seahorsepip whatever.  Just show me some code.